# Apply two color on button background

Tags: html, jquery, css

I need to apply two background color for my button. Need to design the button like below.

[image]

Is this design possible using pure CSS or please provide any other suggestion.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is achievable with [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

The `linear-gradient` stands for four-parameter:

1. **`<angel>`**. Which is the **starting point of `linear-gradient`, so a value of `0deg` is equivalent to `to top;` increasing values rotate clockwise from there**.
2. **`color`**. It will indicate the color of `linear-gradient`, which **can be either `rgb`, `rgba`, or `hex`**.
3. **`<linear-color-stop>`**. This indicates the **stopping point of colors on our `linear-gradient`** (To keep it dynamic for various `width` you should use it with percentage rather than raw numbers.)
4. **`<color-hint>`**. This one indicates an interpolation hint defining **how the gradient progresses between adjacent color stops**. So whenever you set it to `100%` it will come up with a hard line where the gradient changes (It should always set for the last color or by indicating color individually).

```css
linear-gradient(<angel>, color <linear-color-stop> <color-hint>)
```

Your final code should be something like this:

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(40, 141, 211, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(40, 141, 211, 1) 90%, rgba(255, 214, 103, 1) 10% 100%);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: All the answers are the working solution but accepting this answer as explanation was given.

Answer (score 3):

use this clean and simple:

> When you need to have a angled that is when you need a degree in the `linear-gradient` in your case it is top left corner so playing around the numbers will get you things worked.
>
> Make the border thick as you want, I have choose the color and the border as per the picture as well as the width of the button.

NOTE:
if you increase the width of the button, the incline angle will vary so you have to tweak a code for that as well. This is same for all answers posted here.

```css
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, #278CD3 150px, #FFD667 90px, #FFD667 100%);
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #278CD3;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn ">Button</button>
```

Comment: This will break hard on `width` change.

Comment: @SMAKSS as per OP requirement I was able to form this considering basic button size and can be fixed easily by changing angle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css gradient

```css
.btn{
background: rgb(241,157,6);
background: linear-gradient(133deg, rgba(241,157,6,1) 20%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 20%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 100%);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">hello</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, replica.

```css
.btn {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #278CD3;
    background: linear-gradient(315deg,#278CD3 150px, #FFD667 90px, #FFD667 100%);
    font-size:16px;
    color: #FFD667;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: I was thinking what is the difference between my code and yours? `2px` border?

Comment: border radius and text color as well perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

Easier solution will be to use an image like that as the background of the button.

```
<button><img src="pic_trulli.jpg" width="30px" height= "30px"></button>
```

A bit more adjustment with css is needed to make the image to fit into the button

Comment: It's possible with pure css...

Comment: Yes. This is possible. Try something like <button><img src="pic_trulli.jpg" width="30px" height= "30px"></button>

Comment: Yes but question is with pure css. And i think it's not a good idea to load an image for this feature...